# Redis to Postgres via Kafka

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka connect docker image.

My source

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/   -d  '{"name": "redissource","config": {"connector.class": "com.redis.kafka.connect.RedisSourceConnector", "tasks.max": "1","topics": "mystream","redis.uri": "redis://virginia:virginia@172.18.1.41:1235","redis.cluster.enabled": "false",  "redis.stream.name":"mystream",   "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter","value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081" }}'
```

Target

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/   -d  '{"name": "redtopgsink","config": { "connector.class"  : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector", "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://navi1085_postgres_1:5432/postgres", "connection.user" :"postgres",  "connection.password" :"postgres_nave1085",  "topics"  :"mystream", "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter", "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter","value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081" ,   "insert.mode" :"upsert", "schema.pattern":"public","auto.create"  :"true" ,"pk.mode"   :"record_key","pk.fields":"sensor_id",   "delete.enabled"  :"true","auto.evolve":"true"}}'
```

i am getting below error kindly help to resolve this errors.

`{"name":"redtopgsink","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"connect:8083","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:334)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:235)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:204)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:200)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:255)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: null (MAP) type doesn't have a mapping to the SQL database column type\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.getSqlType(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1945)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.getSqlType(PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect.java:332)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.writeColumnSpec(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1861)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.lambda$writeColumnsSpec$39(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1850)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.ExpressionBuilder.append(ExpressionBuilder.java:560)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.ExpressionBuilder$BasicListBuilder.of(ExpressionBuilder.java:599)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.writeColumnsSpec(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1852)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.buildCreateTableStatement(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:1769)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.create(DbStructure.java:121)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:67)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:122)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:74)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:84)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:584)\n\t... 10 more\n"}],"type":"sink"}`

Answer (score 0):

The Redis source connector only creates String, Bytes, or [Map schema](https://redis-field-engineering.github.io/redis-kafka-connect/#stream-reader) (as mentioned in your error)

The JDBC Sink **requires** a Struct Connect type with typed & named fields. Map values are not guaranteed to have types.

One way to do this would be to [use KSQL and create a Stream from the Redis-sourced topic](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/query-structured-data/#maps), then output the data into a new, structured Avro/JSON topic, by selecting the Map keys, which the Postgres sink can then read.